# How do I Reveal file in Solution Explorer in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is a new [Solution Explorer view](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/project-management#_solution-explorer) with the VS Code C# Dev Kit extension. This view is similar to Visual Studio and it respects .sln configurations.
Is there an option to find the opened file within this view? How do I "Reveal file in Solution Explorer"?